# How To Copy text from a flutter class while adding additional texts to clipboard?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

please can someone show me an example of how to do this? I've tried working with what was explained but anytime I do this.
the info: doesn't allow me to input any texts, it says I can't assign a string to an informationtobecopied.

WILL APPRECIATE IT IF SOMEONE CAN JUST SHOW ME A WORKING EXAMPLE OF HOW TO DO THIS
Here is the link to the question I asked before so you can understand my problem and see my initial question

[How To Copy text from a flutter button class while adding additional texts to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892324/how-to-copy-text-from-a-flutter-button-class-while-adding-additional-texts-to-cl/72081627?noredirect=1#comment127386045_72081627)

here is how I try to call the code in the UI

```
CallingzCard(
toptitle: 'cool',
info: ,
),
```

here is my full code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class InformationToBeCopied {
  final String bottomText;
  const InformationToBeCopied({
    this.bottomText,
  });

  @override
  toString() {
    return 'ive copy this: $bottomText';
  }
}



class CallingzCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String toptitle;
  final InformationToBeCopied info;
  const CallingzCard(
  {
    Key key,
    this.toptitle,
    this.info,
  }) : super(key: key);

  void showtoast() => Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: (info.toString()),
    fontSize: 15,
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        showtoast();
        Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: info.toString()));
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                  blurRadius: 2.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 51, 51, 0.16),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 0, 15),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/phone-call.svg',
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,10,30,0),
                        child: Text(
                          toptitle,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,30,10),
                        child: Text(info.bottomText),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, you are trying to manipulate the text before you save it to the clipboard?

Comment: i literally dont know what im doing. please can you just help with the correct code. so I can see how you do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "$text $additionalText"));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @JeremyCaney You can't explain if this is the best approach. There is no implementation way other than this.

Comment: @Julidi: That may well be, but they can still explain what the methods do, for those unfamiliar.